# I found a headless horseman! Now what?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As I was wandering around the mountains near Rorikstead, I happened upon this interesting character:

[image]

Yup, it's a headless horsemen. He rides pretty fast but I managed to catch up with him. I tried to interact with him but the action wasn't allowed. I followed him for a pretty long while and he seemed to ride in a giant circle (I eventually ended up back near Rorikstead). Any idea if this guy is quest related?

Comment: I found him just standing outside of a cave when I came up...just stood there. Didn't go anywhere...maybe bugged for me too. I'm not sure. As soon as I find him again I'll let you know.

Comment: He is Ragnar The Red from the song because it says he was beheaded in it and it says he went from Rorickstead to whiterun it never says it but thats my guess.

Comment: It's the ghost of Ragnar the Red

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He is *meant* to lead you to a graveyard filled with a bunch of skeletons and a locked master chest filled with a few valuable items.

Not sure why he didn't for you though.

[Source.](http://au.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/The_Headless_Horseman)

Comment: Probably a bug for me - I'll try to go find him again and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: if you look at the coffin to the left there is an axe and a helmet and a skull ... his coffin to the right is his wifes and all the other stones on the floor are his victims burials ... its not quest related , its just a very cool thing in the game:)

Comment: maybe his pathfinding was broken

Comment: or he just couldn't see his way back to the graveyard.

Comment: @Jim, please dont take this personally, but you can not generally add information to somebody elses answer, as this goes against intent. Your edits were still valuable. I would recommend posting as an answer **if you cn find a question asking about the character himself**, else, repost it as a comment.